# Deploying more than two war files in tomcat version 8.5 gives GC limit exceeded error

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, groovy, grails

I am trying to deploy total 4 war files in tomcat server 8.5. All war I have made from groovy and angularJS.
If I deploy any 2 war files, it is working fine, but as soon as I try to deploy third one it gives "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error.

My Server.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="Catalina1">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    <Engine name="Catalina1" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps2"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="Catalina2">
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    <Engine name="Catalina2" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps3"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="Catalina3">
    <Connector port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    <Engine name="Catalina3" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps4"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

</Server>
```

I tried deploying with any 2 war it is working. but I cannot help even after changing settings in server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the memory requirements are for you various war files it'll be hard to give a definitive answer.  But here are some of the things you should look into.

You might need to boost the `-Xmx` setting on the JVM to accommodate all of your applications.  The default maximum memory for out of the box Tomcat is 64mb which is terribly low for production usage.  If you are running on Linux you can adjust this setting by creating a new file `setenv.sh` under  `$CATALINE_HOME/bin`.  On Windows it's `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.bat`.  Then add a line similar to this one:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g"
```

Three parameters you should pay attention to.  The maximum memory setting (-xMx), `-XX:MetaspaceSize`, and `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`.

- The `-xMx` setting controls the upper limit on heap space the VM can allocate.  This is how much memory your programs will have access to store data in memory.
- The `-xMs` setting controls the minimum heap space to allocate.  This can help with startup time if your program uses a bunch of memory upon startup.
- The `-XX:MetaspaceSize` parameter controls how much memory is used to load classes.
- The `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` is the upper limit on the size of memory used to load classes.

Since you are loading several war files into memory I suspect you'll want to increase the Metaspace so all of the class files for each war can fit into memory.  And you'll need to up the memory that each war file will need with -xMx.  You'll need to tweak the numbers I provided to your situation, but that should get it going.

The Metaspace parameters are the "newer" (starting with Java 8) names for the older parameters `PermGenSize` and `MaxPermGenSize` in Java 7 and below.

Another thing is that the error `GC overhead limit exceeded` indicates that the JVM was spending too much time doing garbage collection.  This is evidence that tomcat doesn't have enough memory to start up, and it's thrashing trying to free up memory constantly.  Raising the JVM max memory would probably dramatically help here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will update the answer after trying your suggestion

Comment: If you found this helpful please up vote and accept this as the answer.